# Use of writeDouble produces nonsense

Tags: java

This question is essentially an extension of the discussion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312100/formatted-floating-point-output-in-java).  My goal is to write two formatted columns of arrayed *x* and *y* data to file (type `double`).  My current attempt to accomplish this is as follows:

```
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("angle.txt");
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
  for (i = 0; i < i_max-1; i = i + 1) {
    dos.writeDouble(theta[i]);
  }
  dos.close();
} catch (IOException error) {
  System.out.println("IOException: " + error);
}
```

This code is derived from the example found [here](http://www.java-examples.com/write-double-file-using-dataoutputstream) (DataOutputStream).  Having a limited grasp of Java, I expected this to work for one column only; instead it produced this:

```
?¹™™™™™š?¹™™™™™š?¹™™™™™š?¹™™™™™š?¹™™™™™š?¹™™™™™š?¹™™™™™š?¹™...
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  **Any insights you can offer will be a great help.**

My next question would be: How do I format not one but *two* columns of type `double`, formatted something like `("%1$16.6f, %2$16.6f", time[i], theta[i])`.  Right now I'm following [this](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/297-java-program-format-double-value-2-decimal-places.html) discussion.  However, the compiler dislikes this approach with the use of `writeDouble`.

Your help and patience will be most appreciated.

Comment: First and foremost, you are confusing row-major order with column-major order. C-like languages use row-major, while Fortran uses column-major. See [Row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
try {
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("angle.txt", "UTF-8");
  for (i = 1; i < i_max; i = i + 1) {
    writer.printf("%1$16.6f%2$16.6f%n", time[i], theta[i]);
  }
  writer.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println(ioe);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Streams are used to write binary data. To write textual data, you use Writers. See the Java IO tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html